# Why does the ping command in my batch file execute in a loop and navigates to the beginning?

Tags: batch-file

I created a `.BAT` file in Windows 10 that has the following lines:

```
set /p ipadress="Please select your favourite IP-adress."
echo %ipadress%
ping %ipadress% -n 10
```

However, when I navigate on this batch file to ping, I can see the `ping` command repeatedly being executed in a loop. I even tried to rename the `ping.BAT` to `ping.CMD` but the result is the same.

It works until the second line. After repeating the selected IP address, it ends in a loop and jumps to the beginning of my batch file.

[image: output]

I want to avoid writing `ping` command through the command prompt, which is why I created the batch file. I don't know why the `ping` command is being continuously called when the same statement is put in a batch file.

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser! How is the batch file being called? can you show the output you get?

Comment: the batch file is called "Ping2".

Comment: rename it test.bat and try it again.

Comment: it does the same, it ends in a loop.

Comment: ![output] (https://imgur.com/a/v9KqX3c)

Comment: `1 - Ping` etc. doesn't belong to the code in question. Some other (broader) piece of code loops.

Comment: thanks, now its creepy :) they loop to the german "old" text, which does'nt exist in the batch file anymore.

Comment: Are you sure you're editing and executing the same file?

Comment: yes, we checked this a few times before.

Answer (score 1):

From comments:

> they loop to the german "old" text, which doesn't exist in the batch file anymore

Some old file is named `ping.bat` and it's in the same folder. `ping %ipadress% -n 10` from your new file calls the old file. The old file probably calls `ping` (i.e. itself), hence the loop.

> When a command is issued at the CMD prompt, the operating system will first look for an executable file in the **current folder**, if not found it will scan `%PATH%` to find it.

([source](https://ss64.com/nt/path.html), emphasis mine).

This also explains why there is absolutely no output from the `ping` *utility* in the screenshot you provided.

Solution: delete or rename the `ping.bat` file or explicitly run `ping.exe` to avoid running a different extension file with the same name (in current folder/preceeding in path).

Comment: Or explicitly run **ping.exe** to avoid running a different extension file with the same name. (+1)

Comment: @LotPings Good idea. My answer is now community wiki, it includes your useful comment.

Comment: we checked this again, now we have a "solution". on an another notebook, the batch file is running fine. we think, that we have crashed a system-variable, but we checked this in a tool.now we install windows new. do you have any idea?

Comment: explicitly run ping.exe does not work as well. i mean, we solve the problem. but for the future its cannot be a solution, to install windows again, because of a problem in a batch file.... :-)

Comment: @Nils So maybe your `ping.exe` is broken or there's a "fake" `ping.exe` preceding the right one in your `%PATH`.

Comment: thank you, but why they print out the "old" german version?

Comment: See this: [Is there an equivalent of `which` on the Windows command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/304319) Find out what `ping` resolves to and you will probably find the German text there.

Comment: good morning. with "which command" in front of the ping line it works, but they print an syntax error. do you have any idea?

Comment: @Nils "`which command` in front of the ping line"? Why in front? Do you understand what `which` is in Linux? And why somebody would like to have it in Windows? Do you understand that `command` is a placeholder for actual command like `ping` or whatever? My point was you needed to run `which ping` (or equivalent command) to *find out* what `ping` resolves to, so you could examine the executable found, and maybe it would be this "fake" `ping` with the German text.